# How to create a second RSS in Hugo?

Tags: rss, hugo, facebook-instant-articles

Hugo ships with its own RSS 2.0 template, I'm happy with that and I want to keep it, but I want also to create a second RSS that will be designed for Facebook instant articles.

Is it possible to have more that one RSS ?

If yes, what's the best way to create it ?

Comment: I'd recommend following this issue on GitHub that asks for IA support https://github.com/spf13/hugo/issues/1940 - I am not an expert with Hugo, but would it work to create a new RSS template in `/layouts` and name it `instant-articles.xml` maybe to have a dedicated feed for it?

Answer (score 3):

There is more than one RSS in Hugo, one for the root and then one for each section and taxonomy (tags etc), but it is not possible to create multiple RSS feeds for, say, the home page.

With that in mind, you could create a "dummy section" with a RSS template that use .Site.Pages to create your custom RSS.

Comment: I added this to the Hugo forum:
https://discuss.gohugo.io/t/create-rss-for-facebooks-instant-articles/3246